# perform URL redirection within the mobile apps React Native

Tags: react-native, redirect

I understand there is "Linking" function for react native to perform url redirection which will take the user to the phone's browser. Is there any way to open a URL like https://www.google.com/ within the page inside the apps for both android and ios?

Comment: Use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it using the [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) library. You can create a component for it and use it anywhere you want.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }} />;
  }
}
```